# How to put image as background in Hero Unit?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So far I've got this in my css:

```
hero-unit {
        background-image: myark.jpg;    
}
```

Seems pretty obvious but it doesn't work.

```
.hero_unit{
           }
```

doesn't work either. Sorry. I am new to this if you couldn't tell.

Comment: The most basic of Googling would've gotten you the syntax for this.

Comment: I apologize.I'll do a more thorough search the next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
.hero-unit {
  background-image: url(myark.jpg);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing some thing:

```
.hero-unit {
        background-image: url('myark.jpg');    
}
```

This should work for you. You were missing the `url()` portion of the `background-image` property.